# Building ecommerce

Tags: e-commerce, mobile-application

My company want to build an e-commerce mobile apps. But the thing is I don't have any knowledge on how to start it. The question is, is it enough to have only 2 developer to  conduct this project? if it is enough, how long will it takes to complete the app and launch the app for public use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if SO is the right place for your question, but I think its all about what you want to achieve. The first questions you could ask yourself are:

- Whats the detailed plan?
- Is there any ecommerce project already running (website, processes around (like order management))
- Should it be really a native mobile app or could it be a (mobile first) responsive Shopwebsite?
- Whats the application about (product searching, shopping, something else) ?
- eCommerce projects lives with content, content, content (e.g. product descriptions, category descriptions, blog articles, images). Who delivers this content?
- do you want extra stuff (e.g. push notifications) ?
- Whats the budget?

If there is an ecommerce infrastructure in your company already existing, then achieving an on-top app or website would not be a major case, but of course it should be planned carefully as well.

If your company starts with ecommerce, than you should be realistic: A whole ecommerce project is not as easy as its sounds. And of course it will costs surely an amount of money, time, etc. First you should make a plan. Ask your company stakeholders for this project what they want, whats the budget, etc. Maybe search for ecommerce consulting agencies.

Good Luck :)

Comment: thank you @Stretau . My company never have ecommerce infrastructure. So I don't get the flow to start an ecommerce. When brainstorming session, everything seems just fine. But to execute it quite impossible. Btw, thanks for your answers.